# Android Studio: Not showing preview after adding TextInputLayout in a module

Tags: android-studio, android-textinputlayout

I am learning android development. I have setup a simple app with defaults. In the main app, I have 1 fragment. When I add the `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`, the preview is displayed without any problem.

However, I added another library module, with another fragment. When I add a `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`, the preview stops showing. Below is the stacktrace.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:241)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:211)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:146)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:75)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText.<init>(TextInputEditText.java:70)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText.<init>(TextInputEditText.java:63)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:325)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:174)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:135)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:294)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:417)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:428)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:332)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:359)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:436)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:121)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:717)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$9(RenderTask.java:873)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:192)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I looked around for other similar SO questions and everyone saying to change the app theme.

My question is that, why does android studio shows the preview when I add the `TextInputLayout` to a fragment in main app and why does it not show changes after adding in module.

Android Studio details -

```
Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Beta 5
Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.8774922, built on June 27, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.15.0-46-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    wu.seal.tool.jsontokotlin (3.7.4)
    indent-rainbow.indent-rainbow (2.0.2)
    com.intellij.plugins.macoskeymap (213.5744.3)
    izhangzhihao.rainbow.brackets (6.25)
    com.nbadal.ktlint (0.10.0)

Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME
```

Can someone please help me fix the issue?